# rewriting url with .htacces cause files not to be found

Tags: .htaccess

In general, I am trying to understand how .htaccess works. I would highly appreciate it if anyone points me in the right direction. I have been trying to make the following url (with optional parameters) pretty.

```
mysite/v1.0/foldername

mysite/v1.0/foldername/param1/

mysite/v1.0/foldername/param1/param2/etc
```

I tried the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$    foldername.php [QSA,L]
```

the problem is that when I get it to pass the parameters it can no longer get the resources. It seems to have changed directory.

.htaccess is in *foldername*

Also, I would like to know what site i can go to to learn about REQUEST_URI, REQUEST_FILENAME, etc. A site that is not too technical as it's the apache site.

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly rewriting the rules correct rule according to your need would be like,

```
RewriteEngine On

# rule for removing extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php [QSA,L]

# below cond means incoming url is nor a file neither a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# actual rules
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php?param1=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php?param1=$2&param2=$3 [L]
```

Refrences

- [Reference: mod_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Thanks for the help! But I am still having the same problem ... the resources are not found after rewriting the urls!

Comment: Where are you using the rule in root directory or v1.0 directory try them in v1.0 directory.

Comment: It;s in foldername. It seems like rewriting the url changes directory!

Comment: what? foldername suppose to be a php file as you mention in your example.

Comment: Also please provide your original url which you want to get converted into pretty url.

Comment: I am sorry, you are right. filename is a php file and the filename is in v1.0 Right now I have it localhost so the url goes like this localhost/v1.0/listings and I would like to be able to have multiple subfolders but still be able to load the resources of course!

Comment: What are param1 and param2 then and what is listings now? are you not rewriting to `foldername.php?param1=value` like that?

Comment: I want to remove the extension. Params 1 and param2 are just letters and spaces (although I know that spaces in url are encoded) and they are optional. Thanks!